# Question regarding probability and maximum possible variance

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, variance, expected-value

I have the following question:

Suppose we have a set of 10 numbers (1, 2, ... , 10), each with a certain probability tagged to it.

1. Is it true that the highest possible variance is achieved when 1 and 10 each have probability 0.5 while all other numbers have probability 0?
2. If that is the case, how do we prove this claim? If that is not the case, what is the correct answer then?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Try experimenting with a Beta distribution and look at your findings given changes to alpha and beta hyperparameters. Hint: with hyper parameters both below 1.0, probability density is concentrated in the tails.